# Array Modifier, no Texture on End Cap

Tags: texturing, modifiers

I'm on blender 2.90, trying to attach an end cap with a texture to an Array that's following a curve.
Though for some reason in the array the texture is not displayed.

I have no idea what's going on. Scale is on 1.0 for both objects, texture is mapped to the UV coords and I even tried adding the textured material to the Array.

[image: what it's supposed to look like]
what it's supposed to look like

[image: what it looks like in the array]
what it looks like in the array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is [an old limitation](https://developer.blender.org/T31278), it seems.

To make it work, you need to place the material (only one) of the start/end caps as first material in the material slots of the arrayed object.

[image]

If the caps have two different materials, that won't work (only one is taken into account).